# Laravel 4: How would you integrate user definable templates?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel-4

I am building an application in Laravel 4. This application needs to be skinnable by the client.  In essence, the owner of the app needs to be able to create his own template / styling / layout for his version, and upload it (ideally in a zip). Could you suggest any ideas / best practices / tips for building in functionality where this is possible?

Where should I locate the templates?  Would you use the app/views folder or would you create a writable folder in the public folder?

Any ideas or suggestions or even links to a tutorial would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell the way this is handled in Laravel is to use cascading views and a view namespace. Creating a namespace is easy, just pick a name and add the paths you want it to search in in the order of priority.

```
View::addNamespace('template', ['path/to/public/views', 'path/to/app/views']);
```

Now, when using `View::make` you can prefix with your namespace and it'll first search in **path/to/public/views**, if the view is not there it will then look in **path/to/app/views**. This is extremely handy when you want to provide a sort of base template and simply allow them to provide their own templates that overwrite the base.

Here is how you reference the namespaced views.

```
return View::make('template::example.view');
```